# Transaction Number / Invoice Number Length limit

Tags: acumatica

I am working with the Acumatica Webservice as described here.

http://www.acumatica.com/technical-tuesday-doug-johnson-connecting-website-acumatica/

**I would link to know about the field length limitations for the system.**

I have reviewed the "Segmented Keys" where we can set the GL Account length.
as mentioned in 
http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/pdf/F100_Financials_Basic_Guide_5_0.pdf#page=15&zoom=auto,56.692,738.698

Thank you

Comment: are you asking about how to know the max allowed character length of specific field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the max length for any field in acumatica, what you can do is that go to the DAC definition and see the PXDB

Eg: For invoice reference number, youcan see the type is string and the max length is 15 from the below info.

> DAC: ARInvoice, Property: RefNbr
>
> [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask =
>   ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]